# Confusion with understanding the fixed bias circuit

Tags: transistors, biasing, bipolar

Below shows a bipolar transistor in fixed current bias configuration. A text says that this topology is independent of β:

[image]

What I understand is, since Vcc, Vbe and Rb is constant the base current becomes fixed as:

Ib = (Vcc-Vbe) / Rb

As we see in the above formula since all three variables Vcc Vbe and Rb  are constant, Ib is constant and so fixed.

My confusion is the following:

Imagine if we now change the transistor with the same type but with a different β, will the Ic change?

Thought 1:
I'm asking because I guess we can say that after the transistor is changed the Vbe will not change(?). And according to the Ebers Moll equation the Ic will not change since Vbe will not change.(Ic is determined by Vbe)

Thought 2:
But if we think again after changing the same type transistor with different β which means Vbe will not change and so that means Ib is fixed at the same value as well. But now the new transistor has a different β and Ic = β × Ib. So this tells us that Ic will change.

Which thought above is correct and where am I making the logical flaw?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the Ic will change when a beta value change and Vbe also. In this circuit, only Ib current is fixed (not exactly true). And in real life, you shouldn't use this type of a biasing circuit.

Comment: So the root reason that the β changes the change in Vbe by construction?

Comment: But you are saying Ib is fixed, how come Ib is fixed if Vbe changes? For Ib to be fixed Vbe should be constant isnt it? Maybe I have a problem in the meaning of "fixed" here..

Comment: Every single BJT's will have a different β value. So the Ic will also change. If Vcc >> Vbe we can assume that the Ib ≈ Vcc/Rb is more or less fixed.

Comment: Or maybe your book treat the BJT as a current controlled current source (Ic = Ib x β ) with the fixed Vbe value. In this case, only change in β can change the Ic value.

Comment: The change in Vbe for different transistors is usually small compared to Vcc, so Vbe is (essentially) fixed in comparison to other voltages. Since Ib is determined by RB and Ohm's Law, the value of Ib is also (essentially) fixed. You are correct that changes in β will therefore cause large changes in Ic and Vce.

Comment: In real life, β will change with temperature, but also with the collector current, the β will change. The Vce voltage also slightly change the β value.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Assuming no temperature change. If Vbe is is (essentially) fixed Ebers Moll eq. says Ic should not change. But since beta changes by replacing the transistor Ic = beta*Ib so Ic changes. Do you get where I am confused. Ic is determined by only directly by Vbe so Ic should not change. On the other hand if Vbe is fixed so Ib this yields Ic changes with different beta. Summary Im still confused.

Comment: I don't understand your statement that Ebers-Moll says Ic must be fixed if Vbe is fixed. Where are you getting this idea? Are you neglecting the factor alpha?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Hmm I see maybe Im looking at the simplified equation. You can write an answer if you figured out my problem btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ebers-Moll equation does account for changes in \$\beta\$, but they use a parameter \$\alpha\$ where

$$\alpha = 1 - \frac{1}{\beta} $$

We often say that \$V_{BE}\$ is fixed in this circuit because the changes in \$V_{BE}\$ are usually small compared to \$V_{CC}\$. It follows that \$I_B\$ is (essentially) fixed since it is determined by Ohm's Law and the voltage drop across RB.

Your understanding is correct then that if \$\beta\$ (or \$\alpha\$) changes then \$I_C\$ will change significantly, causing \$V_{CE}\$ to change proportionally.